# EC2 Node backend app [504 gateway timeout]

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, pm2

Works for a couple of hours and then I receive a 504 gateway timeout error on the backend of the application.

EC2 instance is running ubuntu with nginx and PM2.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available` .conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/app;
  index index.html;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
```

I believe my configuration is correct as it works correctly, but only for a few hours. Then I get the error. PM2 instance is still online and running. I think it's probably the node app crashing for some reason, but how can I troubleshoot this on ubuntu EC2? It works perfectly on my local machine.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your node application?

Comment: I don't believe I'm logging errors for node on the server, I need to do this manually right?

Comment: Check PM2 documentation: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/

Comment: Oh right yeah, I've checked the pm2 logs - doesn't seem to be any errors!

Comment: @John107 - you ever get this?

Comment: @jarodsmk added an answer that worked for me, took many hours of searching and adjusting the config to find what worked. But specifically the answer below helped me.

Comment: @John107 thanks man. I ended up having a coding optimization issue myself which I sorted out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent hours on this. Turns out PM2 and Nginx don't always work well together, changing the Nginx config and restarting Nginx and pm2 eventually fixed the problem for me.

Specifically, adding these two lines:

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
keepalive_timeout 10;
```